# Tinymce selfhosted with Vue 3 fails to load styles

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tinymce

I am trying to set up TinyMCE in self-hosted mode, in a Vue3 + webpack app.

I have installed tiny using the following npm coomands:

```bash
npm install tinymce@^5
npm install "@tinymce/tinymce-vue@^4"
```

So far, the editor component works but not all styles and some plugins are not loaded, giving the following errors in console:

"Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8100/js/plugins/link/plugin.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/js/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

My guess would be that I am either not importing correctly or not doing the init correctly?

Console:
[image: browser console screenshot]

EditorComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <page-component>
    <header-component />
    <content-component>
      <editor
        tinymce-script-src="assets/tinymce.min.js"
        v-model="content"
        :init="init"
      />
    </content-component>
  </page-component>
</template>

<script>
import "tinymce/tinymce";
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.css";
import "tinymce/themes/silver";
import "tinymce/icons/default";

/* Import plugins */
import "tinymce/plugins/advlist";
import "tinymce/plugins/autolink";
import "tinymce/plugins/lists";
import "tinymce/plugins/image";
import "tinymce/plugins/charmap";
import "tinymce/plugins/print";
import "tinymce/plugins/preview";
import "tinymce/plugins/anchor";
import "tinymce/plugins/searchreplace";
import "tinymce/plugins/visualblocks";
import "tinymce/plugins/code";
import "tinymce/plugins/fullscreen";
import "tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime";
import "tinymce/plugins/media";
import "tinymce/plugins/table";
import "tinymce/plugins/paste";
import "tinymce/plugins/help";
import "tinymce/plugins/wordcount";

import Editor from "@tinymce/tinymce-vue";

import HeaderComponent from "../components/HeaderComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  components: {
    Editor,
    HeaderComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content: "",
      init: {
        height: 500,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
          "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime media table paste help wordcount",
        ],
        toolbar:
          "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
           alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
           bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help",
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, for anyone who has the same issue:

It seems that tynimce.js tries to load some extra styles by path, which does not quite work with webpack. Fortunately, as per [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/webpack-es6-npm/), an option is provided to disable this behavior, and load the styles from strings.

So here is how I got rid of the errors:

EditorComponent.vue

```js
....
// Added the following missing imports

/* content UI CSS is required */
import contentUiSkinCss from "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.css";

/* The default content CSS can be changed or replaced with appropriate CSS for the editor content. */
import contentCss from "tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css";

// Missing plugin
import "tinymce/plugins/link";

export default {
  name: "Editor",
  components: {
    Editor,
    HeaderComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      content: "",
      init: {
        height: 500,
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
          "searchreplace visualblocks codesample fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime media table paste help wordcount",
        ],
        toolbar:
          "undo redo | codesample | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
           alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
           bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help",
        skin: false,          // disable import of skins
        content_css: false,   // disable import of css
        content_style:
          contentUiSkinCss.toString() + "\n" + contentCss.toString(),  // add styles as strings
      },
    };
  },
};
```